# Segmentation fault for a similar line to working line

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, polymorphism

I am starting to learn C++ by working on a project. I am now blocked with a segmentation error, and I am even more puzzled by the fact the segmentation error happens on a line (second call to whatAmI()) that is very similar to a line that is working properly (first call to whatAmI(). Thank you very much for helping me understand what I am missing.

Here is the code from main():

```
AutoPlayer playerWhite = AutoPlayer();
AutoPlayer playerBlack = AutoPlayer();

std::cout << playerWhite.whatAmI() << std::endl;
std::cout << playerBlack.whatAmI() << std::endl;

BGame bgame = BGame(&playerWhite, &playerBlack);

std::cout << "Black" << std::endl;
std::cout << bgame.playerBlack->whatAmI() << std::endl;
std::cout << "White" << std::endl;
std::cout << bgame.playerWhite->whatAmI() << std::endl;
```

When executed this code returns:

```
A auto player
A auto player
Black
A auto player
White
Process finished with exit code -107``3741819 (0xC0000005)
```

The constructor of BGame:

```
BGame::BGame(Player *playerWhite, Player *playerBlack):playerWhite(playerWhite), playerBlack(playerBlack)
{}
```

The declaration of BGame:

```
class BGame
{
public:
    BGame(Player *playerWhite, Player *playerBlack);

    Player *playerWhite = 0;
    Player *playerBlack = 0;
};
```

The declaration and code of a player:

```
class Player
{
private:
    Colors playerColor;
public:
    Colors getColor();
    void setColor(Colors);
    virtual std::string whatAmI();
    Brain brain;

};

Colors Player::getColor()
{
    return playerColor;
}

void Player::setColor(Colors color)
{
    playerColor = color;
}

string Player::whatAmI()
{
    return "A base player";
}
```

The declaration and code of an AutoPlayer

```
class AutoPlayer :  public Player
{
public:
    virtual std::string whatAmI();
    Brain brain = Brain();
};

std::string AutoPlayer::whatAmI()
{
    return "A auto player";
}
```

Edit:

Adding the Colors definition:

```
enum class Colors {WHITE, BLACK};
```

Comment: This example completes successfully for me. What compiler and what compilation flags are you sing?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As it stands now, your example is incomplete.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: How is that possible when there is no definition of `Brain` or `Colors`?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And did you try to run your code in a debugger?

Comment: @AndyG You can omit anything that refers to those types. They are not used by this example unless their default constructors have side effects. It's likely that code was meant to be excluded by OP.

Comment: Testing, but I’m pretty sure that your parameter names for the `BGame` constructor are hiding the data members and causing you to dereference a `nullptr`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
Colors is a enum. Brain is a larger class, using a few other classes that use many parts of the rest of the code. The constructor has no side effect, and I have tested that I can call the default constructor without error.

The c++ compiler is g++ from MinGW

Davislor, can you please explain me what you mean when you say the parameter names for the BGame constructor are hiding the data members ?

Comment: All the pieces may or may not be here, but I can't be bothered to put them together into something I can work with. Moving on.

Comment: I posted my hypothesis as an answer, but it got downvoted.  I mean that your BGame constructor uses the same names for its parameters and the data members, you write `:playerWhite(playerWhite)`, and therefore I suspect the compiler doesn’t know which `playerWhite` you mean and is initializing the data members to garbage instead of to the parameter values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I turn the program into a MCVE, I can’t reproduce this bug on either clang++ or g++.  However, I have a suspicion what is going on.  You call the following constructor for `BGame` (reformatted):

```
BGame::BGame( Player *playerWhite,
              Player *playerBlack )
  : playerWhite(playerWhite),
    playerBlack(playerBlack)
{}
```

You use the same names for the data members and the parameters, so if your compiler initializes `playerWhite` to itself instead of your parameter, it will hold garbage.  See if changing the parameter names to `black` and `white` fixes the bug.

Here’s the MCVE I turned your fragments into, by the way.  Please try to post MCVEs in the future:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum class Colors {WHITE, BLACK};
struct Brain {};

class Player
{
private:
    Colors playerColor;
public:
    Colors getColor();
    void setColor(Colors);
    virtual std::string whatAmI();
    Brain brain;

};

Colors Player::getColor()
{
    return playerColor;
}

void Player::setColor(Colors color)
{
    playerColor = color;
}

std::string Player::whatAmI()
{
    return "A base player";
}

class AutoPlayer :  public Player
{
public:
    virtual std::string whatAmI();
    Brain brain = Brain();
};

std::string AutoPlayer::whatAmI()
{
    return "A auto player";
}

class BGame
{
public:
    BGame(Player *playerWhite, Player *playerBlack);

    Player *playerWhite = 0;
    Player *playerBlack = 0;
};

BGame::BGame( Player *playerWhite,
              Player *playerBlack )
  : playerWhite(playerWhite),
    playerBlack(playerBlack)
{}

int main(void) {
    AutoPlayer playerWhite = AutoPlayer();
    AutoPlayer playerBlack = AutoPlayer();

    std::cout << playerWhite.whatAmI() << std::endl;
    std::cout << playerBlack.whatAmI() << std::endl;

    BGame bgame = BGame(&playerWhite, &playerBlack);

    std::cout << "Black" << std::endl;
    std::cout << bgame.playerBlack->whatAmI() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "White" << std::endl;
    std::cout << bgame.playerWhite->whatAmI() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for turning the code into a MCVE.
This code did not run for me. Now I have changed the compiler, and it works.
I think I should have tried that before, but I did not expect the compiler to be the problem, rather an error in my code somewhere - and your answers helped me to clarify that.